# css flex-direction: row but items in col order

Tags: css

A two col layout like:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  border: 2px solid red;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 1%;
}
li {
  flex-basis: calc(49vw - 10px); 
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
</ul>
```

Does nicely layout two cols like

```
text1 text2
text3 text4
```

What needs to be changed (in css) that items are ordered like?

```
text1 text3
text2 text4
```

Comment: This feels like you're using `display: flex` to achieve something that could be achieved more easily with [`column-count: 2`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egq9zsph/).

Comment: Flex direction column and a fixed height are required

Comment: David yes, column count might be a way. Unfortuantely it tear apart some li an puts it in the next row :/

Comment: Pauli_D what if the height is different between items?

Comment: To ping someone you need to preface their user-name with an `@` symbol; as an example: typing `@P` will bring up a clickable suggestion of a user that's participated in comments whose user-name begins with 'p' (it's not case-sensitive). As for the tearing apart, there are fixes for that, such as [`break-inside: avoid`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egq9zsph/1/). But whether that's suitable depends on your use-case and requirements.

Comment: thanks @DavidThomas your answer solves my problem. If you post it as answer I can accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is as below, relying on CSS multi-column layouts instead of flex-box or grid:

```js
// utilities:
const D = document,
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  fragment = () => D.createDocumentFragment(),
  getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)],
  // a simple function to generate a random number between the supplied
  // minimum and maximum:
  getRandom = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };

// here we retrieve an Array of all <li> elements:
getAll('li').forEach(
  // we use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
  // all elements in the Array, and pass a reference
  // to the Array-element ('el') into the function
  // body:
  (el) => {
    // we use a template literal string to interpolate
    // the result of getRandom(3, 9) into a string with
    // which we can set the height of the current <li>:
    let blockSize = `${getRandom(3, 9)}em`;
    // we update the CSS custom property to that size:
    el.style.setProperty('--randomHeight', blockSize);
    // and set the text of the <span> element to state
    // the defined size:
    get('span', el).textContent = blockSize;
  });
```

```css
/* the question asks for two columns, though I'm explicitly
   defining 3 here, to demonstrate a problem with this approach
   as-is: */
ul {
  /* removing the default list-style: */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* defining the number of columns: */
  column-count: 3;
}

li {
  /* setting the block-size of the element
     to the value of the --randomHeight
     custom property or to 2em if the
     property is invalid or absent: */
  block-size: var(--randomHeight, 2em);
  background-color: hsl(100deg 90% 70% / 0.3);
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: hsl(200deg 90% 70% / 0.3);
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List-item: 01<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 02<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 03<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 04<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 05<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 06<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 07<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 08<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 09<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 10<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 11<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 12<span></span></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egq9zsph/2/).

It may take a few runs to realise, but if you look at the layout it becomes obvious that the `<li>` elements fragment from – for example – the end of one column to the start of the next. This is due to fragmentation, which is to be expected as the browser will try to match column-sizes within the container.

To avoid that, we can use the `break-inside` property on the `<li>` elements, and set it to `avoid`; in the following example we have two `<ul>` elements, the first does *not* have `break-inside: avoid` specified on the `<li>` elements, the second does. This should allow for a clear visualisation of the layout difference:

```js
const D = document,
      get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
      fragment = () => D.createDocumentFragment(),
      getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)],
      getRandom = (min, max) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
      },
      frag = fragment();

getAll('li').forEach(
  (el) => {
    let blockSize = `${getRandom(3, 9)}em`;
    el.style.setProperty('--randomHeight', blockSize);
    get('span', el).textContent = blockSize;
    frag.append(el.cloneNode(true));
  });

get('ul.column-contained').append(frag);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  column-count: 3;
}

ul.column-contained>* {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

li {
  block-size: var(--randomHeight, 2em);
  background-color: hsl(100deg 90% 70% / 0.3);
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: hsl(200deg 90% 70% / 0.3);
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List-item: 01<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 02<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 03<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 04<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 05<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 06<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 07<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 08<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 09<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 10<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 11<span></span></li>
  <li>List-item: 12<span></span></li>
</ul>

<ul class="column-contained">
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/egq9zsph/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
  - [`break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside).
  - [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).
  - [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
  - [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array` literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`Document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
  - [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
  - [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped :)